# Show force update in older application to current app

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am trying to update my old application which is already installed on iPhone devices.

Is there any solution for my older app, that is already installed on iOS devices, to be forcefully updated? I did not implement force-update code using an API in the older application. But right now I want all users to come to the new latest version of my app.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: No. There's no way to force an old app to be updated. If the user turned off automatic updates then that is their choice.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way,
but if your API network call error handling in the mobile app is implemented with a *show* **Alert** or **Toast** with Error response **500** series and your API had **Version** for example:

```
https://yourbaseUrl/v1/user
```

you can implement backward compatibility in your backend API if the version API was for example **v1** with error response status code 500 and message "Please Update Your App to last Version 'your-last-version'"

if the application returns the Server error as an alert or Toast you can help your old user to update the application.